# Why the object has no attribute that is already defined in another module?

Tags: python

I am testing a code written and posted on the website

http://foreverlearning.altervista.org/genetic-programming-symbolic-regression-pt-3/

The portion of the code is located at the bottom part of the webpage. When running the test code mainpova.py, I am getting the syntax error.

The syntax error is,

```
python mainprova4.py
Best solution is ((3*(1*2))+x) with error 20.0...
Producing gen number 2...
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "mainprova4.py", line 68, in <module>
main()
 File "mainprova4.py", line 62, in main
gen.next(crossoverPerc, mutationPerc, randomPerc, copyPerc,shouldPruneForMaxHeight, minHeight, maxHeight, minValue, maxValue, variables, operators)
AttributeError: 'Generation' object has no attribute 'next'
```

The code of mainprova4.py is

```
import generation as gn
import tree as tr
import generator as gtr
import math

xs = [-1, 1, 0, 3, -2, 0, -1, 3, 2, -2] # Values of x
ys = [1, 1, 0, 2, -2, 5, 3, -1, 5, -4] # Values of y
zs = [3, 3, 1, 12, 3, 6, 5, 9, 10, 1] # Values of z, from z = x^2 + y + 1

def main():
    minHeight = 1
    maxHeight = 5
    minValue = 1
    maxValue = 3
    variables = ["x", "y"]
    operators = ["+", "-", "*"]

    numOfMembers = 150
    maxNumOfGenerations = 500
    currentGen = 1
    crossoverPerc = 0.5
    mutationPerc = 0.3
    randomPerc = 0.1
    copyPerc = 0.1
    shouldPruneForMaxHeight = True



    # Step 1: create first generation
    gen = gn.Generation()
    for i in range(0, numOfMembers):
    gen.addMember(gtr.getTree(minHeight, maxHeight, minValue, maxValue, variables, operators))


    for genNum in range(1, maxNumOfGenerations + 1):
       """ Step 2: evaluate all members """
       for memberNum in range(0, gen.size()):
       member = gen.getMember(memberNum)
       totalError = 0
       for i in range(0, len(xs)):
           res = member.eval({"x": xs[i], "y": ys[i]})
           error = math.fabs(zs[i] - res)
           totalError += error
           gen.setError(memberNum, totalError)

       """ Step 3: sort solutions according to errors """
       gen.sort(descending = False)

       """ Step 4: if best solution has error zero, then stop """
       print("Best solution is " + str(gen.getMember(0)) + " with error " + str(gen.getError(0)) + "...")
       if gen.getError(0) == 0:
       break

       """ If limit reached, then stop process """
       if currentGen == maxNumOfGenerations:
          print("LIMIT REACHED")
      break

       """ Step 5: produce next generation """
       currentGen += 1
       print("Producing gen number " + str(currentGen) + "...")
       gen.next(crossoverPerc, mutationPerc, randomPerc, copyPerc, shouldPruneForMaxHeight, minHeight, maxHeight, minValue, maxValue, variables, operators)

    print("END ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
    print("Best solution found is " + str(gen.getMember(0)) + " with error " + str(gen.getError(0)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I dont see that this is indentation problem.  What I am missing here.
The code that has next definition is

```
import random as rnd
import generator as gtr
import treeOperations as trop

class Generation(object):
    def __init__(self):
      self.membersWithErrors = []

    def addMember(self, member):
      """ Add a tree to the generation """
      self.membersWithErrors.append([member, 0])

    def setMember(self, member, index):
      """ Updates the member at the specified position """
      self.membersWithErrors[index] = member

    def setError(self, index, error):
      """ Sets the error of the member at the specified position """
      self.membersWithErrors[index][1] = error

    def getMember(self, index):
      """ Returns the member at the specified position """
      return self.membersWithErrors[index][0]

    def getError(self, index):
      """ Returns the error of the member at the specified position """
      return self.membersWithErrors[index][1]

    def size(self):
      """ Returns the number of members curently in the generation """
      return len(self.membersWithErrors)

    def clear(self):
      """ Clears the generation, i.e. removes all the members """
      self.membersWithErrors.clear()

    def sort(self, descending):
      """ Sorts the members of the generation according the their score """
      self.membersWithErrors.sort(key = lambda l: l[1], reverse = descending)

def getMembersForReproduction(self, numMembers, pickProb):
    """ Returns a certain number of distinct members from the generation.
    The first member is selected with probability pickProb. If it's not chosen, the 
    second member is selected with probability pickProb, and so on. """
    selectedMembers = []
    while len(selectedMembers) < numMembers: 
      indexSelected = 0  
      while rnd.randint(0, 100) > int(pickProb * 100) and indexSelected != len(self.membersWithErrors) - 1:
    indexSelected += 1
    memberWithErrorSelected = self.membersWithErrors[indexSelected]
    if memberWithErrorSelected[0] not in selectedMembers:
       selectedMembers.append(memberWithErrorSelected[0])
    return selectedMembers

def next(self, crossoverPerc, mutationPerc, randomPerc, copyPerc, shouldPruneForMaxHeight, minHeight, maxHeight, minValue, maxValue, variables, operators):
    """ It proceeds to the next generation with the help of genetic operations """
    oldMembersWithError = self.membersWithErrors
    newMembersWithError = []
    maxMembers = len(oldMembersWithError)

    numCrossover = int(maxMembers * crossoverPerc)
    numMutation = int(maxMembers * mutationPerc)
    numRandom = int(maxMembers * randomPerc)
    numCopy = maxMembers - numCrossover - numMutation - numRandom

    # Crossover
    for i in range(0, numCrossover):
    members = self.getMembersForReproduction(2, 0.3)
    m1 = members[0]
    m2 = members[1]
    newMember = trop.crossover(m1, m2)
    newMembersWithError.append([newMember, 0])

    # Crossover
    for i in range(0, numCrossover):
        members = self.getMembersForReproduction(2, 0.3)
        m1 = members[0]
        m2 = members[1]
        newMember = trop.crossover(m1, m2)
        if shouldPruneForMaxHeight and newMember.height() > maxHeight:
       newMember = trop.pruneTreeForMaxHeight(newMember, maxHeight, minValue, maxValue, variables)
    newMembersWithError.append([newMember, 0])

    # Mutation
    for i in range(0, numMutation):
        m1 = self.getMembersForReproduction(1, 0.3)[0]
        newMembersWithError.append([trop.mutation(m1, minValue, maxValue, variables, operators), 0])

    # Random
    for i in range(0, numRandom):
    newMembersWithError.append([gtr.getTree(minHeight, maxHeight, minValue, maxValue, variables, operators), 0])

    # Copy
    members = self.getMembersForReproduction(numCopy, 0.3)
    for m in members:
        ewMembersWithError.append([m.clone(), 0])

    self.membersWithErrors = newMembersWithError
```

Comment: According to the indention, `next` isn't a method of the class. How is it indented in your actual code?

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There is just too much code here that does not, at all, pertain to the problem. I'm not going to dig through all that and I suspect others won't either.

Comment: Your `next` definition is not inside the `Generation` class. It is indeed an indentation problem.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: The indentation is wrong starting at `def getMembersForReproduction`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the error highlighted here:

```
import random as rnd
import generator as gtr
import treeOperations as trop

class Generation(object):
    def __init__(self):
      self.membersWithErrors = []

    def addMember(self, member):
      """ Add a tree to the generation """
      self.membersWithErrors.append([member, 0])

    def setMember(self, member, index):
      """ Updates the member at the specified position """
      self.membersWithErrors[index] = member

    def setError(self, index, error):
      """ Sets the error of the member at the specified position """
      self.membersWithErrors[index][1] = error

    def getMember(self, index):
      """ Returns the member at the specified position """
      return self.membersWithErrors[index][0]

    def getError(self, index):
      """ Returns the error of the member at the specified position """
      return self.membersWithErrors[index][1]

    def size(self):
      """ Returns the number of members curently in the generation """
      return len(self.membersWithErrors)

    def clear(self):
      """ Clears the generation, i.e. removes all the members """
      self.membersWithErrors.clear()

    def sort(self, descending):
      """ Sorts the members of the generation according the their score """
      self.membersWithErrors.sort(key = lambda l: l[1], reverse = descending)

############ INDENTATION PROBLEM ################
def getMembersForReproduction(self, numMembers, pickProb):
    """ Returns a certain number of distinct members from the generation.
    The first member is selected with probability pickProb. If it's not chosen, the 
    second member is selected with probability pickProb, and so on. """
    selectedMembers = []
    while len(selectedMembers) < numMembers: 
      indexSelected = 0  
      while rnd.randint(0, 100) > int(pickProb * 100) and indexSelected != len(self.membersWithErrors) - 1:
    indexSelected += 1
    memberWithErrorSelected = self.membersWithErrors[indexSelected]
    if memberWithErrorSelected[0] not in selectedMembers:
       selectedMembers.append(memberWithErrorSelected[0])
    return selectedMembers

############ HERE IS THE INDENTATION PROBLEM ########## 
def next(self, crossoverPerc, mutationPerc, randomPerc, copyPerc, shouldPruneForMaxHeight, minHeight, maxHeight, minValue, maxValue, variables, operators):
    """ It proceeds to the next generation with the help of genetic operations """
    oldMembersWithError = self.membersWithErrors
    newMembersWithError = []
    maxMembers = len(oldMembersWithError)

    numCrossover = int(maxMembers * crossoverPerc)
    numMutation = int(maxMembers * mutationPerc)
    numRandom = int(maxMembers * randomPerc)
    numCopy = maxMembers - numCrossover - numMutation - numRandom

    # Crossover
    for i in range(0, numCrossover):
    members = self.getMembersForReproduction(2, 0.3)
    m1 = members[0]
    m2 = members[1]
    newMember = trop.crossover(m1, m2)
    newMembersWithError.append([newMember, 0])

    # Crossover
    for i in range(0, numCrossover):
        members = self.getMembersForReproduction(2, 0.3)
        m1 = members[0]
        m2 = members[1]
        newMember = trop.crossover(m1, m2)
        if shouldPruneForMaxHeight and newMember.height() > maxHeight:
       newMember = trop.pruneTreeForMaxHeight(newMember, maxHeight, minValue, maxValue, variables)
    newMembersWithError.append([newMember, 0])

    # Mutation
    for i in range(0, numMutation):
        m1 = self.getMembersForReproduction(1, 0.3)[0]
        newMembersWithError.append([trop.mutation(m1, minValue, maxValue, variables, operators), 0])

    # Random
    for i in range(0, numRandom):
    newMembersWithError.append([gtr.getTree(minHeight, maxHeight, minValue, maxValue, variables, operators), 0])

    # Copy
    members = self.getMembersForReproduction(numCopy, 0.3)
    for m in members:
        ewMembersWithError.append([m.clone(), 0])

    self.membersWithErrors = newMembersWithError
```

This is how it should be:

```
import random as rnd
import generator as gtr
import treeOperations as trop

class Generation(object):
    def __init__(self):
      self.membersWithErrors = []

    def addMember(self, member):
      """ Add a tree to the generation """
      self.membersWithErrors.append([member, 0])

    def setMember(self, member, index):
      """ Updates the member at the specified position """
      self.membersWithErrors[index] = member

    def setError(self, index, error):
      """ Sets the error of the member at the specified position """
      self.membersWithErrors[index][1] = error

    def getMember(self, index):
      """ Returns the member at the specified position """
      return self.membersWithErrors[index][0]

    def getError(self, index):
      """ Returns the error of the member at the specified position """
      return self.membersWithErrors[index][1]

    def size(self):
      """ Returns the number of members curently in the generation """
      return len(self.membersWithErrors)

    def clear(self):
      """ Clears the generation, i.e. removes all the members """
      self.membersWithErrors.clear()

    def sort(self, descending):
      """ Sorts the members of the generation according the their score """
      self.membersWithErrors.sort(key = lambda l: l[1], reverse = descending)

    ########## YOU HAVE TO FIX THIS TOO ############
    def getMembersForReproduction(self, numMembers, pickProb):
        """ Returns a certain number of distinct members from the generation.
        The first member is selected with probability pickProb. If it's not chosen, the 
        second member is selected with probability pickProb, and so on. """
        selectedMembers = []
        while len(selectedMembers) < numMembers: 
          indexSelected = 0  
          while rnd.randint(0, 100) > int(pickProb * 100) and indexSelected != len(self.membersWithErrors) - 1:
        indexSelected += 1
        memberWithErrorSelected = self.membersWithErrors[indexSelected]
        if memberWithErrorSelected[0] not in selectedMembers:
           selectedMembers.append(memberWithErrorSelected[0])
        return selectedMembers

    ############ This is the proper identation #############
    def next(self, crossoverPerc, mutationPerc, randomPerc, copyPerc, shouldPruneForMaxHeight, minHeight, maxHeight, minValue, maxValue, variables, operators):
        """ It proceeds to the next generation with the help of genetic operations """
        oldMembersWithError = self.membersWithErrors
        newMembersWithError = []
        maxMembers = len(oldMembersWithError)

        numCrossover = int(maxMembers * crossoverPerc)
        numMutation = int(maxMembers * mutationPerc)
        numRandom = int(maxMembers * randomPerc)
        numCopy = maxMembers - numCrossover - numMutation - numRandom

        # Crossover
        for i in range(0, numCrossover):
        members = self.getMembersForReproduction(2, 0.3)
        m1 = members[0]
        m2 = members[1]
        newMember = trop.crossover(m1, m2)
        newMembersWithError.append([newMember, 0])

        # Crossover
        for i in range(0, numCrossover):
        members = self.getMembersForReproduction(2, 0.3)
        m1 = members[0]
        m2 = members[1]
        newMember = trop.crossover(m1, m2)
        if shouldPruneForMaxHeight and newMember.height() > maxHeight:
           newMember = trop.pruneTreeForMaxHeight(newMember, maxHeight, minValue, maxValue, variables)
        newMembersWithError.append([newMember, 0])

        # Mutation
        for i in range(0, numMutation):
            m1 = self.getMembersForReproduction(1, 0.3)[0]
            newMembersWithError.append([trop.mutation(m1, minValue, maxValue, variables, operators), 0])

        # Random
        for i in range(0, numRandom):
        newMembersWithError.append([gtr.getTree(minHeight, maxHeight, minValue, maxValue, variables, operators), 0])

        # Copy
        members = self.getMembersForReproduction(numCopy, 0.3)
        for m in members:
            ewMembersWithError.append([m.clone(), 0])

        self.membersWithErrors = newMembersWithError
```